# Disable Horizontal Scroll in Mobile While Allowing position:sticky

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to disable the horizontal scroll in mobile browsers. I tried:

```css
body {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```

However, while this worked for mobile Safari, users can still scroll horizontally on mobile Google Chrome. I also have several menus with `position: sticky`, and if I changed it to

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```

horizontal scroll on mobile Google Chrome is disabled but the `position: sticky` doesn't work anymore. Is there a solution that could allow me to concurrently disable horizontal scroll on mobile Google Chrome and allow `position: sticky`? I checked out several tutorials but none would allow both.
Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. Surprised no one has provided a solution for this yet. Did you find one?